# Question on separable field extenions

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

Hi I was given this question which I cannot express myself mathematically on so would indeed like the help and appreciate it
I am given $ K/F $ is a finite field extension. I am required to show that K is separable if and only if there is a finite number of separable elements
$ \alpha_1, \alpha_2,...,\alpha_n \in K $ such that $ K = F[\alpha_1, \alpha_2,...,\alpha_n] $. First direction is obvious seeing as how if i know it is separable and finite then in particular the finite set of generators is separable but how to show that if K is generated by a finite number of separable elements then K itself is separable? Any help appreciated
Thank you all

Comment: You need a theorem that says that a compositum of separable extensions will itself be separable. Depending on your definition of separability, it can be easy to prove.

Comment: Here @Lubin I want to mention one thing that even before proving that compositum of separable extension is separable; he has to prove that for a simple extension if the minimal polynomial of that single element is separable then the whole extension is separable which is not trivial as well.

Comment: Right, @Gimgim. I think that when you define separability for extensions by the number of monomorphisms into an a.c. field, and separability for polynomials (elements) by the number of distinct roots, this part of it shouldn’t be too hard. As early as possible, you establish logical relations between the two concepts.

Comment: Precise you have to create a bridge in between embedding( no of mono) and roots of the polynomial. I think even the given answer is wrong although that is accepted by kroner!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $E$ be the splitting field over of the set of minimal polynomials for $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n$.  Since $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n$ are separable, $E/F$ is Galois.  Let $\alpha\in K=F[\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n]$.  Then the minimal polynomial for $\alpha$ over $F$ splits in $E$ (all irreducible polynomials that have a root in a Galois extension, split in that extension).  The splitting field $L$ of $\alpha$ is therefore an intermediate field of the Galois extension $E/F$ and therefore $L/F$ is Galois.  Every element of a Galois extension of $F$ is separable.  Thus $\alpha$ is separable.

Comment: Why is $L/F$ Galois? If $K/F$ is Galois then $K/L$ is Galois not necessarily $L/F$..

Comment: @Gimgim Hi, it's because L is a splitting field of $\alpha$ and therefore necessarily Galois.

Comment: Hi, when you are using that splitting field of a separable polynomial is Galois then in that statement you are using several equivalent definition of Galois extension where you are actually using this fact that an extension is separable if that is splitting field of some separable polynomials. So you are actually getting a rounded arguement